# use d3 to create neo4j node tooltip

Tags: d3.js, neo4j

[image]

When using neo4j, if you click the node, the circle tooltip will be shown with three new features.

I am just wondering how to have this kind of tooltip by using d3. Does anyone has any ideas how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example to get you started.

It displays a circle and its concentric "tooltip" arcs when it's clicked:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 200;

var svg =
  d3.select("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
    .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

var clicked = false;

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", 45)
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("stroke", "light-grey")
  .on("click", addOrRemoveTooltip)
  .attr("cursor", "pointer");

function addOrRemoveTooltip() {

  if (clicked) {
    d3.selectAll("path").remove();
    clicked = false;
  } else {

    var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(47).outerRadius(80);

    svg.selectAll("arcs")
      .data([
        { start: 0, end: 1/3 },
        { start: 1/3, end: 2/3 },
        { start: 2/3, end: 1 }
      ])
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", d => arc({
        "startAngle": d.start * 2 * Math.PI + 0.01,
        "endAngle": d.end * 2 * Math.PI - 0.01
      }))
      .attr("fill", "lightgrey");

    clicked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

---

The circle is given a listener on clicks:

```
svg.append("circle").on("click", doSomething)
```

When the circle is clicked, this listener is activated and draws 3 arcs this way:

```
var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(47).outerRadius(80);

svg.selectAll("arcs")
  .data([
    { start: 0, end: 1/3 },
    { start: 1/3, end: 2/3 },
    { start: 2/3, end: 1 }
  ])
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", d => arc({
    "startAngle": d.start * 2 * Math.PI + 0.01,
    "endAngle": d.end * 2 * Math.PI - 0.01
  }))
```

We then need a global variable which will store the status of the button: if it's clicked or not.

This way when the circle's click listener is activated again, we know that its previous state was clicked, which means the tooltip arcs should be removed:

```
d3.selectAll("path").remove();
```